# LVM: "Volume group is not consistent" and "Incorrect metadata area header" but volume still mountable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, lvm

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with a volume group that has 4 disks in it:

```
  Incorrect metadata area header checksum on /dev/sde1 at offset 4096
  Incorrect metadata area header checksum on /dev/sde1 at offset 4096
  WARNING: Volume Group foo is not consistent
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
  /dev/sda1  foo  lvm2 a--  2.73t      0
  /dev/sdb1  foo  lvm2 a--  2.73t      0
  /dev/sdd1  foo  lvm2 a--  1.36t      0
  /dev/sde1  foo  lvm2 a--  1.36t 703.55g
```

My goal had been to remove /dev/sde1 entirely. I did that by first shrinking the filesystem by 1.5TB (ext4). However, something went wrong, and I'm left in this state. Curiously, the file system still mounts and I can use it. In lieu of just backing everything up and starting over, I'd like to learn how to solve this problem. Everything I've found online mentions that the LV is unmountable, but mine still is.

Below is the output of `vgs` in addition to `pvs` above.

```
[~]$ sudo vgs
  Incorrect metadata area header checksum on /dev/sde1 at offset 4096
  Incorrect metadata area header checksum on /dev/sde1 at offset 4096
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  foo    4   1   0 wz--n- 8.19t 703.55g
```

Comment: gonna assume you ran lvreduce -L1.5T  /path      the missing step is to now  run  lvremove  /path